# Differences between Arduino Uno SMD and Uno DIP

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-uno-smd

I just bought an Arduino Uno (SMD version) from [W11Stop](http://www.w11stop.com/) and want to know whether there is any other difference between Arduino UNO DIP and Arduino UNO SMD besides knowing that the SMD version doesn't have a DIP chip which can be replaced?

I am just a beginner so please help me if I am wrong!

Comment: Afaik, the SMD version actually has two extra analog pins. But they may not be accessible on your Arduino board (ADC6 & ADC7). The PDIP has 28pins TQFP has 32 pins (check the datasheet). But the internals should be the same by design.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no real difference, at least not directly related to the SMD.

There are many clones which sometimes have slightly different behavior or protection.

But for the SMD the only disadvantage is it cannot (easily) be replaced.

I have one original one (with DIP) and several clones and so far I did not found any difference, except for having mini USB instead of normal USB.

Comment: mini USB instead of USB-B is just a chinese version of it. Many clones of Arduino bought from china have either MINI, MICRO or B-type usb port, you can actually choose. But none original(UNO) has ever had a mini USB on it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there are no different on the functionality. But you may can't go through some features, because the ATmega can be remove it manually without any special tools. One of the useful case as [ArduinoISP](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP) for burning bootloader to another ATmega328p AVR.

For personal suggestion, you just needed one piece of PDIP/DIP version UNO, others boards you can consider the lower cost, such as [Nano](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-nano), [Pro Mini](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/arduino-pro-mini)(Without [USB-to-TTL](https://www.adafruit.com/product/954)), UNO(SMD).

For the USB-to-TTL, there are many options in the market, watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vawhrr4COjI) to explain what are they different.

Comment: alright... at least as a starter we could keep continuing the dev under any arduino ....

Answer (score 0):

There's no actual difference, but just the "look". Neither version of it should bother you at anything, but there are 2 things, worth mentioning.

1. The IC can fall out of DIP socket: I've been told a few times this already, but never had experienced such behaviour or been at occasion, where that happened.
   So here's a **disadvantage** for DIP cases.
2. DIP has also possibility of changing waaaaaaaaaay easier the microprocessor in case of failure. You simply grab it off (even might with a help of a screwdriver) and you're ready to put in a new one. So this is an **advantage nr. 1**.
   I also like to use an Arduino in projects, but not the whole board. I just take the IC (atmega328) and use 2 ceramic caps with 16MHz quartz and I've got my own arduino on other PCB - in this case, you can use Arduino UNO board as a programmer. This is how to avoid installing FTDI or CH340 chip on other boards.
   **Advantage nr. 2.**